# How do I execute a certain code and then back at my main code

Tags: java, boolean

So I want to find a way to execute my code and then back to my main code. I'm new at java so please dont judge my bad code :)
Anw so i have this piece of code and i want it to be activated only if the user inserts the number 2 at the code Below

```
Boolean CitizenPhase=false;
            while(CitizenPhase){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome To our Market. I see you need resources to please your citizens. Well You came to the right place!", "Global Market", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                String MarketBuy=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose What you want to buy \n 1.Corn ("+StockCorn+"$) Increases Hapiness by 40 \n 2.Cotton ("+StockCotton+"$) Increases Hapiness by 10 \n 3.Oranges ("+StockOrange+"$) Increases Hapiness by 15 \n 4.Silver ("+StockSilver+"$) Increases Hapiness by 100 \n 5.Sugar ("+StockSugar+"$) Increases Hapiness by 45 \n 6.Coffee ("+StockCoffee+"$) Increases Hapiness by 35 \n 7.Rice ("+StockRice+"$) Increases Hapiness by 25", "Global Market");
                if(MarketBuy.equals("1")){
                    MoneyCount-=StockCorn;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Buy Successfull. You now have "+MoneyCount+"$ left!", "Global Market",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    CitizenPhase=false;
                    MainMenu=true;
                }if(MarketBuy.equals("2")){
                    MoneyCount-=StockCotton;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Buy Successfull. You now have "+MoneyCount+"$ left!", "Global Market",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    CitizenPhase=false;
                    MainMenu=true;
                }if(MarketBuy.equals("3")){
                    MoneyCount-=StockOrange;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Buy Successfull. You now have "+MoneyCount+"$ left!", "Global Market",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    CitizenPhase=false;
                    MainMenu=true;
                }if(MarketBuy.equals("4")){
                    MoneyCount-=StockSilver;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Buy Successfull. You now have "+MoneyCount+"$ left!", "Global Market",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    CitizenPhase=false;
                    MainMenu=true;
                }if(MarketBuy.equals("5")){
                    MoneyCount-=StockSugar;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Buy Successfull. You now have "+MoneyCount+"$ left!", "Global Market",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    CitizenPhase=false;
                    MainMenu=true;
                }if(MarketBuy.equals("6")){
                    MoneyCount-=StockCoffee;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Buy Successfull. You now have "+MoneyCount+"$ left!", "Global Market",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    CitizenPhase=false;
                    MainMenu=true;
                }if(MarketBuy.equals("7")){
                    MoneyCount-=StockRice;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Buy Successfull. You now have "+MoneyCount+"$ left!", "Global Market",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    CitizenPhase=false;
                    MainMenu=true;
                }
            }
```

Below is here..  So this code should start the code above.. but it says that the variable CitizenPhase does not exist... Ik that this happens because this code is above the code above xD confused? So is there another way than using MainMenu=false; CitizenPhase=true; to start a piece of code? Thank you for your time :)

```
if (Buy1.equals("2")) {
                    MainMenu=false;
                    CitizenPhase=true;
                }
```

Comment: Just a tip, you might want to use `else if` to make your program faster. Using only `if`'s iterates through all the possibilities which takes time. `else if` will only check if the ideal occurrence has not yet been completed.

Comment: Why you do while on a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `CitizenPhase` declaration before the checking like:

```
Boolean CitizenPhase=false;
if (Buy1.equals("2")) {
   MainMenu=false;
   CitizenPhase=true;
}

while(CitizenPhase){...
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually did that everytime but i forgot to do it on this one. It works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

We need more of the code. You are testing a conditional on `Buy1` but it isn't declared in what you've shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a method? ie:

`public static void method1(){
//insert above code here
}`

`if (Buy1.equals("2"){
  method1();}`